# Prestashop Controller - Change the current store on Multistore

Tags: php, prestashop

I have a multistore environment on a prestashop. I created a module with a controller to change store if postal code is not correct. The problem comes when I use `Tools::redirect($newUrlToRedirect);` it redirects to my current store, and I need it redirects to another store. This is my code:

```
class cartportkeyDeriverModuleFrontController extends ModuleFrontController   {
    public function init(){
        //I am in the url http://localhost/shopgroup/shopnameCART/quick-order and 
        //check the postal code, then clicking a link I go to the URL 
        //http://localhost/shopgroup/shopnameNEW/index.php?fc=module&module=cartportkey&controller=deriver&id_cart=XXX&id_shop=YYY
        parent::init();
        $id_cart = (int)Tools::getValue('id_cart');
        $id_shop = (int)Tools::getValue('id_shop');
        $this->context->cookie->id_cart = $id_cart;
        $link_order = $this->context->link->getPageLink('order');
        $testShop = Context::getContext()->shop;
        //HERE I OBTAIN THE storeOLD instead storeNEW so I am redirecting again to storeOLD
        $testShop = json_decode(json_encode($testShop), true);
        $newUrlToRedirect = "http://".$testShop['domain'].$testShop['physical_uri'].$testShop['virtual_uri'].'quick-order';
        //print $newUrlToRedirect;
        $cart = new Cart(33);
        $cart->delete();
        Tools::redirect($newUrlToRedirect);
    }
    public function initContent() {
        parent::initContent();
    }

}
```

I had put some clarifications in the code as comments. The question is, how can I change the active store??

Answer (score 0):

I have found my own answer. Instead of getting the context in `$testShop = Context::getContext()->shop;`

Change that line for:

```
$testShop = new Shop($id_shop);
$testShop->getContext();
```

Everything fine. Thanks!